# Download own module with pip, "No module named ..."

Tags: python, pip, package, setup.py, pypi

I am in the process of building my own Python module, just to get a hang of how it works. My Python is decent, but I have never build or submitted any packages before.

I followed a guide on [Python Hosted](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) as well as [the official `setuptools` documentation](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) and this article on [python.org](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#setup-args). However, I still can't get this to work.

The package structure, with three modules (FileHelpers, TypeHelpers, XmlHelpers), looks like this:

```
PyLT3/
|- .git/
|- .idea/
|- setup.py
|- __init__.py
|- README.rst
|- LICENSE.txt
|- .gitignore
|- FileHelpers.py
|- TypeHelpers.py
|- XmlHelpers.py
```

Contents of `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='PyLT3',
    version='0.1.3',
    description='A collection of helper functions and NLP scripts',
    long_description='During my time working on the PhD project PreDict, I have written and gathered a bunch of useful functions. They are collected here as part of the PyLT3 package.',
    keywords='nlp xml file-handling helpers',
    packages=find_packages(),
    url='https://github.com/BramVanroy/PyLT3',
    author='Bram Vanroy',
    author_email='bramvanroy@hotmail.com',
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 1 - Planning',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering',
        'Topic :: Text Processing',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    ],
    project_urls = {
        'Bug Reports': 'https://github.com/BramVanroy/PyLT3/issues',
        'Source': 'https://github.com/BramVanroy/PyLT3',
    },
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

Contents of MANIFEST.in:

```
prune .idea/*
```

With this data, I create a distribution:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

And a wheel:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

And the distribution is then uploaded to PyPi:

```
twine upload dist/*
```

To test this out, I download [the package](https://pypi.org/project/PyLT3/) with pip:

```
pip install PyLT3
```

(Also used `pip3`.) It successfully installs.

But when I then try a simple `import PyLT3`, I get an error

> ```
> import PyLT3
> ```
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyLT3'

This is odd, because pip told me the module was successfully installed. So I went looking for the module, and its `*.info` is installed in `C:\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\PyLT3-0.1.3.dist-info`. But I am assuming that this is not the actual package but just an info directory. There is no other package (e.g. `PyLT3/`).

All of this leads me to believe that I did something wrong when *packaging*. What did I forget?

Comment: Do you see `FileHelpers.py`, etc. in your site-packages? My preferred way of packaging python is to put all the source files (including `__init__.py` into subdirectory of the project. In your case, this would end up like `PyLT3/PyLT3/__init__.py`

Comment: @Yossarian No, they're not there either. Only the info file. Do you mean that each module goes into its own folder with its own init, or just that I need one over-arching parent directory with the same name as the package?

Comment: @BramVanroy According to https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#directory-structure you should have at least one "parent" directory with an `__init__.py` file (which may be empty) You can remove the top-level `__init__.py`

Comment: A "general" trick: before uploading to pypi, you may find useful to pip install your dist file into a fresh brand new virtual environment on your local machine. This way you can check the install does work, or not, as well as the library/application and avoid uploading the same (patched) several times.

Comment: D'oh, silly mistake! I thought that the parent directory of your `setup.py` was actually the package you were creating, but it is not! Silly me. Thanks, I fixed the error and uploaded a new version. Seem to be working now. Please someone post an answer that includes this information in some detail, and I'll accept it asap.

Comment: @zezollo I'm going to try to do that from now on! As I said, I'm new to all this so I'm happy to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your package doesn’t register a package named `PyLT3`.

Your project stucture should look like this:

```
PyLT3/  # This is your project directory. Its name is irrelevant from the packaging point of view.
 |- .git/
 |- .idea/
 |- setup.py
 |- README.rst
 |- LICENSE.txt
 |- .gitignore
 |- PyLT3/  # This is directory holds your python package.
     |- __init__.py
     |- FileHelpers.py
     |- TypeHelpers.py
     |- XmlHelpers.py
```

You can try this locally by running `pip install -e .` from your project directory. This allows you to validate this works, before you publish.

A personal note: I would also strongly suggest using lower case package and module names, as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wasn't aware of the naming convention. I updated the package to reflect that. Thank you.